# Katalon Studio 6.2.2 by default generates scripts in groovy language, is there a setting using which scripts can be generated by default in Java?

Tags: katalon

Is there a way to get scripts in Java when I record using Katalon studio ?

[image: Check the Script tab]

Answer (score 1):

Yes!! you can export scripts in JAVA, by using a chrome browser plugin
[Katalon Recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid)

Follow this link for steps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322028/1976848